# Why is my recursive function returning an empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nested-lists

The problem that I had to tackle was **creating a function that recursively flattens a nested list.**

The following below is my code.

What I don't understand is how the program keeps returning an empty list.
I realize that I had to initialize an empty list and that could be the problem here but how else could I tackle this?

```
def flat_list(nested_lst, low, high):
   new_lst = []

   if low >= high:
       return new_lst

   if type(nested_lst[low]) is list:
       for item in nested_lst[low]:
           new_lst.append(item)
       return flat_list(nested_lst, low+1, high)
    
   else:
       new_lst.append(nested_lst[low])
       return flat_list(nested_lst, low+1, high)


def main():
   lst = [[1], [[2, [3], 4], 5], 6]

   print(flat_list(lst, 0, len(lst)-1))


main()
```

Comment: Use an IDE like Pycharm to track each recursion cycle. That'll help you a lot.

Comment: I followed the first comment's advice and it seems like the function is creating a new empty list every recursive cycle but I don't understand how else to define the list and append to it?

Comment: It isn't clear how the parameters `low` and `high` are even relevant to the problem. You seem to be over-complicating it.

Comment: The low and high were required for the problem, they're just for the user to enter where in the list to start and end the flattening.

Comment: "The low and high were required for the problem" -- not in the problem that you described in the question that you posted, which was simply about flattening a nested list.

Comment: Define one function that is independent of low and high.  Then another function will call that with the appropriate slice of the original list, then replacing the slice with the flattened returned value.

Comment: I changed the code so it pops after appending to the new list but its still giving an empty list. Also sorry for not making it clear but there's lot of rules for my assignment. I don't think I can create another function either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this clause is exemplary of your problems:

```
   for item in nested_lst[low]:
       new_lst.append(item)
   return flat_list(nested_lst, low+1, high)
```

You append stuff onto `new_lst`, then completely ignore it in your returned result!

The larger problem, typical of folks new to recursion, is insisting on sticking a `for` in the middle of your recursive function! The key is to think recursively, and trust recursion to do the work:

```
def flat_list(nested_lst):
    if nested_lst:
        head, *tail = nested_lst

        return (flat_list(head) if isinstance(head, list) else [head]) + flat_list(tail)

    return nested_lst

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [[1], [[2, [3], 4], 5], 6]

    print(flat_list(lst))
```

You see that it can be done without `low` and `high`, so now it's a matter of adding them back since you're required to use them.

> that code that @RufusVS posted is to go inside the flattening function
> or does it go in the main function?

I pesonally would say, "neither".  I'd wrap the code of @RufusVS around my recursive function:

```
def flat_list(nested_list, low, high):

    def flat_list_recursive(nested_lst):
        if nested_lst:
            head, *tail = nested_lst

            head = flat_list_recursive(head) if isinstance(head, list) else [head]

            return head + flat_list_recursive(tail)

        return nested_lst

    new_list = list(nested_list) # shallow copy

    new_list[low:high] = flat_list_recursive(nested_list[low:high])

    return new_list
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = [[1], [[2, [3], 4], 5], 6]

    print(flat_list(lst, 1, 2))  # [[1], 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: In this context, asterisk is an unpacking operator.  The first element of `nested_list` gets put into `head`, the reading elements get put into `tail`.  Equivalent to `head, tail = nested_list[0], nested_list[1:]`

Comment: So, in light of my other comment, you can call this *excellent* function with: something close to:  `orig_list[low:high]=flat_list(orig_list[low:high])`  to fit the original requirements.

Comment: that code that @RufusVS posted is to go inside the flattening function or does it go in the main function?

Answer (score 2):

Either of the functions can be coerced into using low and high by doing something like:

```
def flat_list(nested_list, low=None, high=None):   # arguments are optional
    if low is None:
        # put block contents of either no-arg answers in here
    else:
        nested_list[low:high]=flat_list(nested_list[low:high])
        return nested_list
```

Comment: My concern is that this would modify the argument `nested_list` so I used a shallow copy in my implementation of your approach.

Comment: @cdlane - you are right.  This is actually the first time I've ever actually done assignment to a slice.   using `return nested_list[:low]+flat_list(nested_list[low:high))+nested_list[high:]` might be better than slice assignment for the reason you give.

Answer (score 1):

A more readable example:

```
def flat_list(nested_lst):
   new_lst = []
   
   if type(nested_lst) is list:
       for item in nested_lst:
           new_lst += flat_list(item)
   else:
       new_lst.append(nested_lst)
       
   return new_lst
```

If you pursue a 'purer' recursive function, remove the for loop. It would be like:

```
def flat_list(nested_lst):
   if not nested_lst:
       return []
   
   head, *tail = nested_lst
   if type(head) is list:
      return flat_list(head) + flat_list(tail)
   else:
      return [head] + flat_list(tail)
```

Comment: Interesting, how could you incorporate high and low parameters into this?

Comment: Added an answer using low and high arguments.

Comment: @Sesame If you just want flat a list, low and high is not necessary for such work. I just new another list in every iteration by remove low and high. If you want to avoid extra construct you can add high/low point back.